# Get value from a ConstantExpression

Tags: c#, reflection, expression

I'm looking to get a value from an

```
var guid = Guid.Parse("SOMEGUID-GUID-GUID-GUID-SOMEGUIDGUID");
Expression<Func<Someobject, bool>> selector = x => x.SomeId == guid;
```

For logging purposes I need to be able to fish out that guid.

I tried the following code, which I feel is somewhat close to what I'm looking for, but not quite.

```
BinaryExpression binaryExpression = (BinaryExpression)selector.Body;
MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)binaryExpression.Right).Operand;
ConstantExpression constantExpression = (ConstantExpression)memberExpression.Expression;
```

Now, ConstantExpression exposes a member 'Value', which does contain what I'm looking for, but I'm a bit puzzled how to actually extract this.

And no:

```
var val = (Guid)constantExpression.Value;
```

Does not work :)

**SOLVED**

The end result looks like:

```
BinaryExpression binaryExpression = (BinaryExpression)selector.Body;
MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)binaryExpression.Right).Operand;
var myGuid = Expression.Lambda(memberExpression).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

**Follow-up**

I did some rudementary speed testing using the following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var id = Guid.Parse("bleh");

        Expression<Func<Thingemebob, bool>> selector = x => x.Id == id;

        var tickList = new List<long>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            GetValueWithExpressionsAndReflection(selector);
            sw.Stop();
            tickList.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
        }

                    Trace.WriteLine("GetValueWithExpressionsAndReflection: Average over 100000, first call included: " + tickList.Average());
        Trace.WriteLine("GetValueWithExpressionsAndReflection: First call: " + tickList[0]);
        Trace.WriteLine("GetValueWithExpressionsAndReflection: Average over 100000, first call excluded: " + tickList.Skip(1).Average());

        tickList = new List<long>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            GetValueWithCompiledExpression(selector);
            sw.Stop();
            tickList.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
        }

                    Trace.WriteLine("GetValueWithCompiledExpression: Average over 100000, first call included: " + tickList.Average());
        Trace.WriteLine("GetValueWithCompiledExpression: First call: " + tickList[0]);
        Trace.WriteLine("GetValueWithCompiledExpression: Average over 100000, first call excluded: " + tickList.Skip(1).Average());

        Debugger.Break();
    }

    private static void GetValueWithCompiledExpression(Expression<Func<Note, bool>> selector)
    {
        BinaryExpression binaryExpression = (BinaryExpression)selector.Body;
        MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)binaryExpression.Right).Operand;
        var o = Expression.Lambda(memberExpression).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
    }

    private static void GetValueWithExpressionsAndReflection(Expression<Func<Note, bool>> selector)
    {
        BinaryExpression binaryExpression = (BinaryExpression)selector.Body;
        MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)binaryExpression.Right).Operand;
        ConstantExpression constantExpression = (ConstantExpression)memberExpression.Expression;

        FieldInfo member = (FieldInfo)memberExpression.Member;
        var instance = constantExpression.Value;
        var guid = member.GetValue(instance);
    }
```

Turns out the compile version is MUCH slower. We're looking at a huge difference. (Timing is in *ticks*):

> GetValueWithExpressionsAndReflection: Average over 100000, first call included: 0,93122
>
> GetValueWithExpressionsAndReflection: First call: 851
>
> GetValueWithExpressionsAndReflection: Average over 100000, first call excluded: 0,922719227192272

Versus:

> GetValueWithCompiledExpression: Average over 100000, first call included: 499,53669
>
> GetValueWithCompiledExpression: First call: 16818
>
> GetValueWithCompiledExpression: Average over 100000, first call excluded: 499,373503735037

Rudementary tests or not: no doubt I will be using the reflection version.
My results seem to be consistent with:
http://www.minddriven.de/index.php/technology/dot-net/c-sharp/efficient-expression-values

Comment: From your first code snippet it seems you have not `Guid` but `string`, if you're not _sure_ about its format you may even just use `Converter` class methods.

Comment: What's the value of constantExpression.Value.GetType() and what does that tell you?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I'm very sure about the format, updated the question to reflect this more properly.
 EFAndExpressions.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0, which tells me next to nothing at the moment :)

Comment: Now you have a `Guid` (note it was originally a `string` then you can't cast it to `Guid`) but it's not type you expect (`memberExpression` in this case but even bypassing that it's not a `ConstantExpression`...). According to type you report for it then your real code should be pretty different from example you posted here. Did you write `selector = x => x.SomeId == Guid.Parse("SOMEGUID-GUID-GUID-GUID-SOMEGUIDGUID");` ?

Comment: In the real code it wasn't a string, nor did I pass Guid.Parse to the selector, as EF would not be able to translate that to a store expression. I wrote down a bad example. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Was replying that you already had the member and the dynamic class instance and could do something like `var member = (FieldInfo)memberExpression.Member;
            var instance = constantExpression.Value;
            var inputGuid = member.GetValue(instance);` , but your method of compiling is much better! You should post it as an answer (that is allowed to your own question), so future searches can benefit from it!

Comment: I'll do some rudementary timing and profling to compare our solutions :)

Comment: Cool, I saw the comments on usr's post and wonder if reflection wins versus compiling. PS, you could use `var myGuid = Expression.Lambda<Func<Guid>>(memberExpression).Compile()();` to prevent boxing and unboxing.

Comment: Inital post updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your const expression has type `EFAndExpressions.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0`. This means that the expression has the following structure:

```
var compilerGeneratedClass = new compilerGeneratedClass() {
   guid = Guid.Parse("SOMEGUID-GUID-GUID-GUID-SOMEGUIDGUID"); };
Expression<Func<Someobject, bool>> selector = x => x.SomeId == compilerGeneratedClass.guid;
```

The compiler does this for you. Use a decompiler to check out the details.

Now you know how the expression tree looks like and you can decompose it. You'll need to use reflection to obtain the runtime value of the `compilerGeneratedClass.guid` field or property.

This value is *not* part of the expression tree directly.

Comment: ok, so I'll need to figure out the value using Reflection/FieldInfo etc

Comment: @Apeiron that code works but it is very slow thanks to the Compile() call. Better profile this before it goes to production. Also, it might not scale at all if the JIT is single threaded which I don't know.

Comment: Ok, I'll follow up with some timing results! Thanks for the heads up.